# How to get icon/icon's path of running app in linux/windows?

Tags: python, icons

I'd like to have a list of open windows and its icons and process it with python.
I thought I was close with xprop and wmctrl, but I can't use it for my purpose.
I can get a list of open windows with `wmctrl -l`, but no idea how get an icon/icon path for any of the listed controls.

Please, help :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the module wnck and gtk.

For instance:

```
import pygtk  
pygtk.require('2.0')  
import gtk  
import wnck  

screen = wnck.screen_get_default()  

while gtk.events_pending():  
    gtk.main_iteration(False)  

for w in screen.get_windows():  
    name = w.get_name()  
    icon = w.get_icon()
    ...
```

Where *name* is a string and *icon* is a GdkPixbuf.

You can read the API documentation for *libwnck* at http://developer.gnome.org/libwnck/stable/WnckWindow.html, which is for C.  However, for Python you only have to remove the prefix wncK_window.  If the documentation say wnck_window_get_name(), then in Python would be my_window.get_name().

*libwnk* is specific to XWindow, hence you can not use it on MS Windows. In that case, you can use other modules that precisely helps on that.  Check the answer for [Get list of open windows in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022219/get-list-of-open-windows-in-python/2023404#2023404)

Comment: This is what I want, you are genius. Do you have any idea how to handle that with MS Windows?

Comment: @xliiv, I added a reference to a similar question but limited only to MS Windows.  It was answered by @reckoner.

Comment: sudo apt-get install python-wnck will take care of 'ImportError: No module named wnck'