# Linux get window icon by pid

Tags: c++, linux

Does anyone know how to get a window icon by PID in Linux?
Me interest only examples on C++ with Xlib or on Java with JNA.

PS. Excuse me for my English.

Comment: PIDs don't have window icons, and one process (e.g. pid) may have multiple windows, or none at all - Linux is not a natively graphical system. There will be plenty of PIDs that have absolutely nothing to do with the Xwindow system and have no windows, period.

Comment: Yes, I understand it. And I precisely know that necessary process has a one or more windows.

Comment: I think what Marc wanted to express was that if PID's aren't necessarily associated with any particular window there probably won't be any standard way to obtain a window icon from a PID.

Answer (score 0):

You could use GTK, loop through open windows, check their PID and grab the icon from the window:

[How to get icon/icon's path of running app in linux/windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5810399/how-to-get-icon-icons-path-of-running-app-in-linux-windows)