# Get HWND of each Window?

Tags: python, windows, hwnd

I am developing a python application and I want to get the `HWND` of each open windows. I need the name of the windows and the `HWND` to filter the list to manage some specifics windows, moving and resizing them.

I have tried to do it myself looking information around but I did not get the correct piece of code. I tried with this [code](http://sjohannes.wordpress.com/2012/03/23/win32-python-getting-all-window-titles) but I only get the title of each windows (that is great), but I need the `HWND` too.

```
import ctypes
import win32gui
EnumWindows = ctypes.windll.user32.EnumWindows
EnumWindowsProc = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_bool, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int))
GetWindowText = ctypes.windll.user32.GetWindowTextW
GetWindowTextLength = ctypes.windll.user32.GetWindowTextLengthW
IsWindowVisible = ctypes.windll.user32.IsWindowVisible

titles = []
def foreach_window(hwnd, lParam):
    if IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
        length = GetWindowTextLength(hwnd)
        buff = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(length + 1)
        GetWindowText(hwnd, buff, length + 1)
        titles.append((hwnd, buff.value))
    return True
EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc(foreach_window), 0)

for i in range(len(titles)):
    print(titles)[i]

win32gui.MoveWindow((titles)[5][0], 0, 0, 760, 500, True)
```

There is a error here:

```
win32gui.MoveWindow((titles)[5][0], 0, 0, 760, 500, True)
 TypeError: The object is not a PyHANDLE object
```

Comment: SO isn't a supermarket where you can go with a shopping list and let others do your work for you. What have you done yourself?

Comment: @Difusio: I have tried to do it myself looking information around but I did not get the correct piece of code. I tried with this http://sjohannes.wordpress.com/2012/03/23/win32-python-getting-all-window-titles/ but I only get the title of each windows (that is great), but I need the HWND too.

Comment: What me means is, please _post_ the _code_ you wrote (either based on what you found, or even copied) along with _errors_ you received or other things you've done.

Comment: Please don't edit your question to include the fixes from the answer, because that makes your question useless to anyone who comes along later and wants to understand it.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You mixed up `ctypes` and `win32gui`.
The `hwnd` you've got is obtained via `ctypes` and is a `LP_c_long` object. That's why `win32gui.MoveWindow` didn't accept it. You should pass it to

```
ctypes.windll.user32.MoveWindow(titles[5][0], 0, 0, 760, 500, True)
```

If you want to use `win32gui.MoveWindow`, you can use python function as callback directly. 
 For example,

```
import win32gui

def enumHandler(hwnd, lParam):
    if win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
        if 'Stack Overflow' in win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd):
            win32gui.MoveWindow(hwnd, 0, 0, 760, 500, True)

win32gui.EnumWindows(enumHandler, None)
```

Comment: great answer! made my browser window jump across three monitors :-D

Comment: Very useful clarification. Basically do not mix ctypes and win32gui. This simple line can save a lot of time :)

Answer (score 2):

To get the handles of all available main windows you pass 0 to `win32gui.EnumChildWindows` then check to make sure the window has text of length longer than 0 (since you want only actual windows not hidden/temporary/popup/special windows).

Comment: i want to do the opposite i.e get the window text whenever a popup/prompt appears e.g. UAC Prompt. What should I do? because it returns none for uac prompt.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem (now that martineau has fixed your original problem of not storing the `HWND` values at all) is that you're trying to mix `ctypes` and `win32gui`.

You can do that if you know what you're doing—but if not, just don't do it.

If you want to get window handles you can use with `win32gui`, use [`win32gui.EnumWindows`](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32gui__EnumWindows_meth.html) instead of calling the raw function out of the `user32` DLL.

Comment: For the record, I didn't fix any original problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just modify the piece of [code](http://sjohannes.wordpress.com/2012/03/23/win32-python-getting-all-window-titles/) for getting all titles so it  does something like this:

```
titles.append((hwnd, buff.value))
```

The `titles` list will then be a list of tuples containing the HWND **and** the title text.

Comment: Thank you very much but this is that happends: (<__main__.LP_c_long object at 0x022A9030>, u'Spotify') I dont get the int that later i will use with win32gui.MoveWindow(hwnd, 0, 0, 760, 500, True). How can I get this number??

Comment: I have updated the post with your help. But I cant use the HWND values in the win32gui.MoveWindow() function. Why?

Comment: In theory you should be able to use `hwnd.contents.value` to get the integer value, but on my system that hangs for unknown reasons. The problem is you're mixing `ctypes` `PyHANDLE` and `win32` `c_long` types. I think @abarnert has the right idea to avoid mixing them.

Comment: @martineau the problem seems to be that the second parameter to WINFUNCTPYE should be HWND, not a pointer.