# How to get Ubuntu Terminal's window handles using Python?

Tags: python, ubuntu, terminal, window

For running few tests on two different serial ports i.e. `ttyS0` and `ttyS1`, I need to work on two different terminal windows or tabs, as the commands I have to run should type simultaneously through Python script.

My prior experience was automating some tasks on Windows OS and with the help of `win32gui` library for Python it was easy to get window handles.I took help from here for this [HWND of each window in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653168/get-hwnd-of-each-window-python)

But, I couldn't find any library that can help me around here in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

This gives you the name of the current tty in Python:

```
import os,sys

os.ttyname(sys.stdout.fileno())
```

If you need it in the Unix terminal then a simple `tty` is your friend. Then you can do e.g. `echo hello > /dev/pts/#` to write to your neighboring tab or window.