# Access variable inside an non-return function from other package without global variable

Tags: python

Is there a method to access a function result, which I have applied another function onto it. For example:

```
win32gui.EnumWindows(a_function, extra)
```

The EnumWindows will iterate all top-level window and passing hwnd into the a_function.

If I set some condition to grep the hwnd I want, we need to yield the hwnd id

Is there a method to access some return/yield from a_function. Instead of the function EnumWindows will grep the return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`EnumWindows` doesn't return anything.** The way results are usually retrieved from it is often to make the callback function store data in a global. There's an example of doing that in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653168/get-hwnd-of-each-window-python).

Another way is to pass a mutable container object (such as a `list`) as the `extra` argument, which will then be passed to the callback as its second argument each time it's called (the first argument is a window handle).

Here's an example using the second technique which passes a local list object to `EnumWindows()` which the callback function modifies, but only if the window is visible.

```
import win32gui

def my_callback(hwnd, list_object):
    if win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
        title = win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)
        if title:
            list_object.append(title)

def print_windows_titles():
    my_list = []  # local variable

    win32gui.EnumWindows(my_callback, my_list)  # populates my_list

    # print result of calling EnumWindows
    print('Titles of Visible Windows:')
    for window_title in my_list:
        print('  {!r}'.format(window_title))

print_windows_titles()
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, It is what I am thinking about. global variable do solve the problem well. As avoiding global variable is a rule of thumb for a beginner, I am thinking about this to figure out whether there is a method to access. manipulation inside the callback and global hwnd is the solution to this questions indeed.

Comment: Do you mean that I can pass an list_object into extra and get the list_object from the function what_i_need_return=win32gui.EnumWindows(a_function, list_object).list_object?

Comment: No. I mean that you can pass a list object to `EnumWindows` and it will be passed to your callback function each time ***it*** is called. But you're right about that being a way of avoiding using a global variable.

Comment: This is very helpful example. Thanks a lot~