# Perform an action if a window with a specific url is open on python

Tags: python

Is there any way to perform an action of a specific URL is open in say a Chrome tab/any other browser?

Comment: I will not downvote, but it would be nice if you explained it better.

Comment: What i mean, is say you opened a tab in chrome with a url say https://www.google.com/  the python script would sense that and say print "Google has been opened"

Comment: You can do something like that on Windows. Maybe other OSs, too.

Comment: Would you care to explain how?

Comment: Even though the title doesn't sound remotely related, check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42178357/355230) to the question [Access variable inside an non-return function from other package without global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42177911/access-variable-inside-an-non-return-function-from-other-package-without-global). The crucial API functions are named `win32gui.EnumWindows()` and `win32gui.GetWindowText()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try writing a [Native Messaging Host](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/nativeMessaging) in Python, plus a Chrome extension, so that every time a certain URL would be open, it would notify the native host.

See this: [Native messaging host in Python](https://github.com/a5482pick/Python-Chrome-App-Native-Messaging)