# How to get the Window handle (hwnd) by Executable path or name?

Tags: python, windows, pywin32, hwnd

Is there a way to get the hwnd-object from a specific window by only providing the executable path or name?

Like `GetForegroundWindow()` from `win32gui` but not just the foreground window.

Id imagine something like this: `GetWindowByPath("C:/mypath/Spotify.exe")` or `GetWindowByName("Spotify")`. Maybe with [ahk](https://pypi.org/project/ahk/)? (I have no clue about AHK)

I've now read other questions and docs for hours and havn't found a way.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This [answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42178357/355230) shows how to do it.

Comment: It's easier to just know the classname of the application's primary HWND in advance. This is easily obtained with the Visual Studio tool Spy++ and inspecting its HWND properties. Then use EnumWindows and similar APIs to find the window you want.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way, you need to approach it from each end and meet in the middle which is the process id.

If this was native code you could use the [Toolhelp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/toolhelp/tool-help-functions) functions to enumerate all the processes and look at the filename of each. When you find a match, remember the process id.

Then you can call `EnumWindows` to find all top-level windows. In the callback you would call `GetWindowThreadProcessId` on each window until you find one that matches the process id you found earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example code to get a list of `hwnd` when giving an exe path.

```
import win32gui
import win32process
import psutil

def GetHwndByPath(path):
    hwnd_list = []

    def winEnumHandler(hwnd, ctx):
        if win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
            thread_id, process_id = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd)
            # Get the process name and executable path
            process = psutil.Process(process_id)
            process_name = process.name()
            process_path = process.exe()
            if process_path == path:
                hwnd_list.append(hwnd)

    win32gui.EnumWindows(winEnumHandler, None)
    return hwnd_list
```

Example usage and output:

```
print(GetHwndByPath("C:\Program Files\DAUM\PotPlayer\PotPlayerMini64.exe"))

# output:
[24389654, 27541266, 22546206]
```

Then you can use the hwnds to do what you want.