# How to programmatically resize process windows in Windows 10?

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, resize

I'm using python to open 4 videos at once with vlc and I want them to be resized automatically in each quarter of the screen (as it happens when you drag the window in the corner).

I'm using the `Popen` method of the `subprocess` library as follows:

```
for i in range(0,4):
    p = subprocess.Popen(['vlc location','file name'])
p.wait()
```

So far the videos open but I can't figure it out how to pin them in the corners like this:

[image: screenshot of desired results]

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14654287/355230) to an unrelated question shows how to use `win32gui.MoveWindow()` to position windows on the Windows desktop (as well as how to iterate through all those that are visible). Something like that is what you need to do.

Comment: Thank you! It solved my problem.

Comment: You're quite welcome. `:-)` When you're allowed to (after a certain amount of time), you can post an answer to your own question which would help others with a similar problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are going to use the Popen subprocess method as I did you will have to remove p.wait() because it will wait for the video to end before running anymore code (it's putting the processes in a queue instead of threading them).

With the help from martineau and the answer he provided I used the following (after installing the pywin32 for python 3.5):

```
import pywintypes
import win32gui

displays = [[-10,0,980,530],
        [954,0,980,530],
        [-10,515,980,530],
        [954,515,980,530]] #these are the x1,y1,x2,y2 to corner all 4 videos on my res (1920x1080)

def enumHandler(hwnd, lParam):
    if win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
        print(win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)) #this will print all the processes title
        if name in win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd): #it checks if the process I'm looking for is running
            win32gui.MoveWindow(hwnd,i0,i1,i2,i3,True) #resizes and moves the process

win32gui.EnumWindows(enumHandler, None) #this is how to run enumHandler
```

The x1,y1,x2,y2 might be different for your processes but these work just fine for vlc media player. I hope I was clear enough but if you don't get it done you should definitely check the answer provided by martineau.