# Find window title of a specific program using ctypes or win32gui?

Tags: python, windows, ctypes, win32gui

My question is similar to this one: [Get HWND of each Window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653168/get-hwnd-of-each-window)
But I need to find windows that belong to a specific program, I'm not familiar with `ctypes` or `win32gui`. Can someone help me?

Comment: Seems like you could use `win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)` to get the title of each window and see if it starts with the name of the specific program (or contains it somewhere, I'm not sure it's always first).

Comment: Look into enumerating the windows on the current desktop via [`EnumDesktopWindows`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682615) and mapping a Window handle to a Process ID via [`GetWindowThreadProcessId`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633522). On the other side of this, create a snapshot via [`CreateToolhelp32Snapshot`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682489) to build a list of Process IDs for a given executable name.

Comment: If you need to be more specific, open a handle to the process via [`OpenProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684320) and get the fully-qualified path via [`QueryFullProcessImageName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684919). Then call [`GetFileVersionInfoEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969434) to verify the file description and version.