# Changing the position of the console window with Python (Windows)

Tags: python, windows, windows-console

Is it possible to change the position of the Windows console through python?
If not, is there any workaround?

I don't know if you would need any specific information, but just in case: I'm using Windows 8.1 (64x), Python 3.5.0, the console is being spawned through `Popen` and the main objective is to move it to the top right corner.

If any info is needed, please let me know.

Comment: Step 1, get the window handle to the console. Step 2, move the window. Is the program that is moving the window the one that used `Popen` or the one that is in the console?

Comment: Preferably the one that used `Popen` (But if you think it would be easier to do it from "inside", it's not a problem)

Comment: Attach to the child's console temporarily via `AttachConsole`. Call `GetConsoleWindow` to get the console window handle. Then detach via `FreeConsole`. Then call `MoveWindow` or `SetWindowPos` to move and resize the console window.

Comment: Could you please put it on an answer with an example? Tried, but I think this is a bit too much for me to understand without an example... (Sorry, still learning the basics of python)

Answer (score 4):

I adapted this from [an answer by NYMK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14654287/3645757)

This will move and resize a single command prompt window (opened by CMD). It is simple and does not handle errors, multiple command prompt windows or command line.

```
import win32gui

appname = 'Command Prompt'
xpos = 50
ypos = 100
width = 800
length = 600

def enumHandler(hwnd, lParam):
    if win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
        if appname in win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd):
            win32gui.MoveWindow(hwnd, xpos, ypos, width, length, True)


win32gui.EnumWindows(enumHandler, None)
```

for a full commandline ready  - try:

```
import win32gui
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("app_name", type=str, default='Command Prompt', help="The window name")
parser.add_argument("xpos", type=int,  default=0, help="x position: 0 or greater")
parser.add_argument("ypos", type=int,  default=0, help="y position: 0 or greater")
parser.add_argument("width", type=int, default=100, help="window width: 10 or greater")
parser.add_argument("length", type=int, default=100, help="window length: 10 or greater")

args = parser.parse_args()

appname = args.app_name
xpos = args.xpos
ypos = args.ypos
width = args.width
length = args.length


def enumHandler(hwnd, lParam):
    if win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
        if appname in win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd):
            win32gui.MoveWindow(hwnd, xpos, ypos, width, length, True)


win32gui.EnumWindows(enumHandler, None)
```