# Set window position in python

Tags: python, windows-10, position

I would like to code a program that open a specific application such as glary utilities and set its (x,y) position on the screen.

For the first part, I know that I can use *subprocess.popen()* but for the position of the window, I don't know what to do.

I thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Doing so—if it's even possible—would depend on your OS.

Comment: I'm on windows 10.

Comment: you can use the `ctypes` library and check out the [Windows API for managing windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-functions), you can call those function with `ctypes`. Or use `win32gui`. Also an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45827930/changing-the-position-of-the-console-window-with-python-windows

Comment: Thanks, I will try this evening

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.