# Scrape Text with python from a terminal

Tags: python, pyautogui

I did a search and i cant find a solution here for my problem.

I'm trying to do a automation with python, that execute actions in a software from my company. The software uses windows cmd terminal as interfaces (conhost.exe).

I have another software that executes and start the process, my automation start when the screen is alredy open.

As the steps of the automation goes on I need to check if the automation is at the right step or if get any message from the system. This is my problem.

I can't find any solution to scrape the text at the window since, all solutions that i found use `subprocess` libary, but I can't see anyway to use subprocess to an alredy open terminal (or cmd).

If I can get the output of the window I search for the text that is needed to be on screen.

Comment: You should be able to use the [`ReadConsoleOutput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsoleoutput) API via PyWin32. (Unfortunately I'm on a Mac right now, so I can't whip up an example.)

Comment: @AKX, I will try. Let you know

Comment: @AKX, it´s possible to show me an example. I did some trys and research but not too much familiar using this lib. I will be much appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A rather brute force approach:

Using [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), take a screenshot of the desired region of the window and [compare it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35176639/compare-images-python-pil) to a template (taken beforehand and saved as a [lossless format](https://www.keycdn.com/support/lossy-vs-lossless#:%7E:text=RAW%2C%20BMP%2C%20GIF%2C%20and,t%20mean%20it%20is%20lossless.) such as png). If the template matches, everything is ok.

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageGrab, ImageChops

template = Image.open("expectation.png")

region = (300, 300, 600, 600)
reality = ImageGrab.grab(region)

if ImageChops.difference(template, reality).getbbox():
    raise AssertionError("This output was not expected")
```

If the command window is not at a specific location, you can [move it to a fixed location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45827930/changing-the-position-of-the-console-window-with-python-windows) yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the asnwer, I do not test yet, I return as ASAP.
But in that case i need to have a screenshot, of every situation possible? Or I need to have the "perfect " example" and see if  the automation is on track?
Other point, its possible to scale using multiple applications at the same time, using this method!?

Comment: @KurtCostaPeters yes, all situations where you need to verify sth would require a (partial) screenshot, and this image needs to perfectly match the template. Multiple apps would only be possible by either bringing each prompt to the front or aligning the prompts in an overlap-free fashion.

Answer (score -2):

Any process printing to the command line would open a TTS file. You will have to find the file and read its contents from Python. FIFO is a great way to capture the output of a process. Overview of how it works:

1. Start the process (the .exe application) and redirect the output to a FIFO file (figure out how you can achieve that in Windows)
2. In another window, run your Python application whose input is the FIFO file (you can redirect that too).
3. While capturing the output, you can decide what step your Application is at and do stuff accordingly.

For your reference:
[FIFO special files](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.3.0?topic=csf-fifo-special-files)

Explore yourself so that you would gain more knowledge than what you actually need.

Comment: *"figure out how you can achieve that in Windows"* How about you tell us how. Advising on using a Unix/Linux specific feature on Windows isn't really useful.