# grabWindow with hwnd return black screen

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qpixmap

Why does grabwindow return black screen? Is a valid window and I do not receive any errors.

```
pix = QPixmap.grabWindow(hwnd)
```

And that way it works perfectly!

```
pix = QPixmap.grabWindow(QApplication.desktop().winId())
```

Below the complete source code:

```
def __init__(self):
    serverProtocol.RDCServerProtocol.__init__(self)
    self._array = QByteArray()
    self._buffer = QBuffer(self._array)
    self._buffer.open(QIODevice.WriteOnly)

def _makeFramebuffer(self, width, height):
    pix = QPixmap.grabWindow(197526) # Google Chrome Window
    pix = pix.scaled(width, height)
    if width >= self._maxWidth or height >= self._maxHeight:
        width = self._maxWidth
        height = self._maxHeight
    pix.save(self._buffer, 'jpeg')
    pixData = self._buffer.data()
    self._array.clear()
    self._buffer.close()
    return "%s" % pixData
```

I need to capture only the google window, but a black screen appears =/

Thank!

Comment: What is the self._buffer object that you save it to?

Comment: @PaulCornelius I updated the question =)

Comment: @rodrigosillos How do you get the hwnd (197526)?, what is your OS?

Comment: Is your chrome window maximised and visible at the time your code calls `grabWindow`?

Comment: @eyllanesc Windows 10

Comment: @three_pineapples Is maximized but not visible

Comment: @three_pineapples But I can close the window of the chrome even not visible

Comment: @three_pineapples Can not capture the window if it is not visible?

Comment: @eyllanesc https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653168/get-hwnd-of-each-window

Comment: No, I don't think you can grab it for minimised windows (at least using that method). The [C++ Qt Docs](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qpixmap.html#grabWindow) say "The grabWindow() function grabs pixels from the screen, not from the window, i.e. if there is another window partially or entirely over the one you grab, you get pixels from the overlying window, too. The mouse cursor is generally not grabbed." By extension I assume that means minimised windows will return nothing.

Comment: @three_pineapples So I need to change the method.
Instead of grab up the pixels, I grab the window screen.
Right?

Comment: @three_pineapples Even with the google chrome window visible I can not grab the pixels, a black screen is displayed =(

Comment: It worked! Only if the window is visible =/
Thank you all!

Comment: @three_pineapples I can not find a method to replace grabWindow.
A method that, instead of grab the screen, grab only the pixels of a specific window.

Comment: I doubt one exists. You're basically asking to inject yourself into the painting event of another program and to read the buffer into which the painting occurs. I doubt there is a general way of doing that for a program.

Comment: @three_pineapples Understood! In fact I wanted to lock the server screen and continue to operate in the background. it is possible? Thank!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171731/discussion-between-rodrigosillos-and-three-pineapples).