# How to maximize an inactive window?

Tags: python, python-3.6, pywin32, win32gui

I have multiple window, but i wish to maximize one of the window only, below is my scripts:

```
import win32gui, win32con
win32gui.ShowWindow('C:/Desktop/UD.ca', win32con.SW_MAXIMIZE)
```

After run this script i get bellow error:

**Error**

```
TypeError: The object is not a PyHANDLE object
```

Anyone have idea on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the [HWND](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Programming/Handles_and_Data_Types#HWND) of the window that you want to maximize. `'C:/Desktop/UD.ca'` is not an HWND. Think of it as a unique ID for a window.

As an example, you can get the HWND of the foreground window by

```
hwnd = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
```

and then pass that in the call to `ShowWindow`,

```
win32gui.ShowWindow(hwnd, win32con.SW_MAXIMIZE)
```

If you want to search all visible Windows for one that contains a title, see  [Get HWND of each Window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653168/get-hwnd-of-each-window)

Comment: May I know how to make unactive window stay active? because once I run on the script, the python console become active window and it will go maximize the python window instead of the window I open in the script

Comment: Like I said, you'd need to find the HWND of the window that you want to maximize. If you open a new window from inside your script, you have to find the HWND of that new window.

Answer (score 1):

This approach worked for me, I combined it with another code to find my window, and worked just fine, thank you. I am looking for a window named "outlook", bring it forward then maximize.

```
 # maximize window
top_windows = []
win32gui.EnumWindows(windowEnumerationHandler, top_windows)
for i in top_windows:
    if "outlook" in i[1].lower():
        print(i)
        hwnd = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
        win32gui.ShowWindow(hwnd, win32con.SW_MAXIMIZE)
        break
```