# how to execute myprogram.exe (in python script ) which open a pop up window , and ask user credentials?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, subprocess

I would like to execute a command (ex: myprogram.exe) in a python script.

the OS is windows 10: Normally, when i execute mycommand.exe in a terminal , it opens another popup windows which prompts the user to enter a credentials (ID and password).

the operation is as follows in command line:

1. bin> myprogram.exe arg1 arg2;
2. (windows open a popup with this message : do you want to allow this app to make changes to your device? -- Yes / no) => user clic yes );
3. another terminal opens which prompts the user to enter Id and password;
4. after hitting enter, mycommand.exe does its job..

Now, I would like to automate this tasks with python script. I use this function with subprocess module:

```
def myfunc():
    command = "..\\bin\\myprogram.exe backup file"
    subprocess.run(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
    return "done!"
```

but as i am new to python, i do not know how to handle the pop up windows that I mentioned above.

need help

I thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done GUI management in Python, but you might want to check out this post that details how to move windows around: [Get HWND of each Window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653168/get-hwnd-of-each-window). You will be able to use the `ctypes` and `win32gui` libraries to mess with your window.