# How to get a specific Windows hwnd with win32gui?

Tags: python, windows, win32gui, hwnd

Okay so I'm using `win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(hwnd_here)` to try and give focus to or at least set to the foreground a specific window. My problem is that the `hwnd` changes each time the program is closed and restarted again.

Is there a way of programmatically getting the specific `hwnd` for that session with a partial window name or title using `win32gui`?

Comment: Use `win32gui.FindWindow`

Comment: See [Get HWND of each Window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653168/get-hwnd-of-each-window)

Comment: Thank you for these answers and the edit of my post! I will make sure to learn how to post properly. My apologies for the initial unedited version. Both of the answers proved useful to me.